# iTunes music from my home linux server to work

Tags: itunes

I have all my itunes music on my nas at home.  I want to be able to listen to it at work.  What's a good method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions :

- Setup a VPN server on you home linux server ([openvpn](http://openvpn.net/)). So you can add your library in itunes at work in the same way you do at home.
- Install [avahi](http://avahi.org/) and [netatalk](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/) will make a convenient file sharing over AFP if you're using a mac
- Setup apache and a web based application that will let you play music in your webbrowser

Comment: For the web based you can use a shoutcast server.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Music Player Daemon](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki). It's lightweight, and trivial to use with a good client (such as [mpc](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Client:Mpc) or [sonata](http://sonata.berlios.de/)). Just network mount your nas on your linux server somewhere, and point mpc to it. The [Archlinux wiki](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Music_Player_Daemon) has a great article on setting it all up.

[Edit]: Incidentally, MPD is pretty good locally too.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestions by Kami you could share the music via a DAAP server like [Firefly](http://www.fireflymediaserver.org/). You should also set up a VPN network to provide authentification.